# Pass C array to python via ctypes

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy

I have a C function which controls a camera, I am trying to send the image buffer to Python via Ctypes to be used in a GUI.

I can grab the buffer, but I am stuck on basically how to get this to work, I suppose I could look into numpy-c api but it looks very confusing.

Thus far I have tried the following:

Create a C array (I guess it is by pointer reference), something like:

```
   UINT16 * MyFunction()
    {

        ...grab image... and return Buffer

        size = 2088 * 2080 * sizeof( UINT16);
        array = (BYTE*) malloc(size);
        API_Write_to_buffer(Buffer, 0, array, size);

        API_Free_Buffer(Buffer);


        return array;
    }
```

I can try to get the return of the array in python:

```
Data = MyFunction() 
array = (c_ubyte * size).from_address(addressof(Data.contents))
```

where MyFunction() looks like the following:

```
def MyFunction():

    MyFunction= lib.MyFunction
    MyFunction.restype = POINTER(c_ubyte)
    img_arr = MyFunction()
    return img_arr
```

Another option is to read line by line using pointers:

```
for(i=0;i<Width;i++)
{
    Ptr = (UINT16*)(bufferPointer + i*bufferWidth);
    for(j=0;j<Height;j++)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

It turns out I need to assign a pointer to my array, but it is a UINT16 in C. When I try to get the array into a numpy array, python crashes. 
I can get this as a return from the wrapper function:

```
def Grab(nframes):

    Grab= 2112 * 2088 * 8   (size of frame width * height * pixelDepth)
    Grab= lib.MyFunction
    Grab.argtypes = [c_uint32]
    Grab.restype = POINTER(c_uint16 * array_length)
    r = Grab(nframes)
    return r
```

Calling the function looks like this:

```
Data = Grab(1)
print Data
```

Which returns this:

```
<__main__.LP_c_ushort_Array_4409856 object at 0x000000000436FE48>
```

Comment: You freed the array before returning it? Wouldn't you get an invalid address at that point, then?

Comment: Indeed, that was a typing mistake on this post, good catch. But I do not have that problem in the actual code. Thanks!

Comment: What does not work? What is the error you get? What are you trying to do that you don't know how to do? The conversion to c_ubyte array looks correct to me. From the question here, it is unclear what is the problem that you have.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a c_ubyte array `img_buffer` and it has a `width` and a `height`, because it is an image.  I'm going to assume that you have that already because it looks like you do in your code.

Your cast for the c_ubyte array should look something like this:

```
img_buffer = (c_ubyte * (height * bytes_per_pixel) *
         (width * bytes_per_pixel)).from_address(addressof(data.contents))
```

You can use numpy to convert it to an ndarray using:

```
import numpy as np

img = np.ndarray(buffer=img_buffer, dtype=np.uint16, shape=(width, height, 1))
```

Once you have the ndarray you can use PIL or matplotlib or OpenCV to show it.

EDIT: Saw that your image is 16-bit so I changed the data type.

Comment: I tried that, but I get : TypeError: buffer is too small for requested array.

Comment: Then your height, width, or data_type doesn't match your c_ubyte buffer size.  Check your buffer size and compare it to what you expect for your image and ensure that they match.